# Error while importing csv file into snowflake - Error: Found character 'W' instead of field delimiter ','

Tags: csv, import, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to import a csv file into Snowflake and I'm getting the below error,

```
Found character 'W' instead of field delimiter ',' .
```

Any leads to fix this error is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vigneswar

Comment: Can you post your COPY INTO and how the file format looks like?

Comment: I'm trying to load the file using Load Table wizard and not through the command line.

Comment: Below is the File format I'm using,

ALTER FILE FORMAT "CDI_SCO_APPS"."CDI_EXECUTIVE_LANDING".CSV_VIGNESH SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 1 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('\\N') COMMENT = 'Format which handle exceptions';

Comment: Your field values are enclosed by double quotes (FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042') which means we expect a comma after (FIELD_DELIMITER = ',') so you might have places with double quotes inside a field value. There you would actually need to escape the double quotes. Have a look at [FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html) docs.